# how can I order tasks swift array appending

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

```
public func downloadAllURL (for path: String, completion: @escaping (Result<[URL], Error>) -> Void) {

        let reference = storage.child(path)
        
        var urlArray: [URL] = []
        
        reference.listAll(complition: { datas, error in
            if error != nil  {
                completion(.failure(StorageErrors.failedToGetDownloadUrl))
                return
            }
            for storageRef in datas.items {
                storageRef.downloadURL{ url, error in
                    if error != nil{
                        completion(.failure(StorageErrors.failedToGetDownloadUrl))
                        return
                    }
                    if let url = url{
                        urlArray.append(url)
                        print(url)
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        print(urlArray.count)
        completion(.success(urlArray))
    }
```

`print(urlArray.count)` always return "0" but append method is working and `print(url)` work correctly.
The problem is my `downloadAllURL` function first print "0" and then print "urls".

Comment: listAll and downloadURL are both asynchronous and return immediately before the callback is invoked.

Comment: How can I make them synchronous

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `completion` **inside** the closure.

Replace

```
})
print(urlArray.count)
completion(.success(urlArray))
```

with

```
    print(urlArray.count)
    completion(.success(urlArray))
})
```